Find the closed orbits of a system
I have the following ODE  and have been tasked to find all of it's closed orbits.
The equation is
$\begin{equation}
x''+(2(x')^2+x^4-1)x'+x^3=0 \end{equation}$
I am really lost on how to start this problem.I tried using the Poincare-Bendixson theorem by rewriting as the following system $\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x'=y \\
      y'=-x^3-y(2y^2+x^4-1) \ 
\end{split}
 \end{equation}$
and after to convert it to polar coordinates but i had no success .I've also tried looking around at other MSE questions relating to orbits but I'm still lost. Any help or direction would be great, thanks!

Hint: Investigate the level curves of $2y^2+x^4$

Hint.
From
$$
\cases{
x' = y\\
y' = -x^3-y g(x,y)
}
$$
we have
$$
\cases{
x^3x' = x^3y\\
yy' = -x^3y-y^2 g(x,y)
}
$$
after addition we have
$$
\frac 14\left(x^4+2 y^2+C_0\right)' = -y^2 g(x,y)
$$
as $g(x,y) = 2y^2+x^4-1$ we have
$$
\frac 14\left(x^4+2 y^2+C_0\right)' = -y^2\left(x^4+2 y^2-1\right)
$$
or
$$
\frac 14\left(x^4+2 y^2-1\right)' = -y^2\left(x^4+2 y^2-1\right)
$$
Follows a stream plot showing the phase plane for
$$
\cases{
x' = y\\
y' = -x^3-y \left(x^4+2 y^2-1\right)
}
$$
and in red the limit cycle represented for $x^4+2 y^2-1=0$.


Thank you so much for anwsering!I think i get it now
